# Find all values of$(1+i)^i=?$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all values of :
>
> $$(1+i)^i=?$$

My Try :

$$A=(1+i)^i \\\ln A= i\ln(1+i)$$

Now we have :

$$e^{2n\pi i} = 1 \ \ \ : \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$ 1+i=\exp \left[ \frac{\ln 2}{2}+i\pi \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \right]$$

Thus :

$$\ln A= i\ln(1+i)=i\ln (\exp \left[ \frac{\ln 2}{2}+i\pi \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \right])$$

So :

$$\ln A= i\ln(1+i)=\exp \left[ \frac{i\ln 2}{2}+i^2\pi \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \right]$$

now what ?

Answer (score 3):

$$(1+i)^i = e^{i \cdot log(1+i)} = e^{i(\ln \sqrt{2} + i(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi))} = e^{i\cdot \ln \sqrt 2} \cdot e^{-(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi)}$$
$$ =(\cos(\ln \sqrt 2) + i\sin(\ln \sqrt 2))\cdot e^{-(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi)}$$

Answer (score 1):

it is $$(1+i)^i=e^{-2\pi n+i\log(1+i)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $1+i$ as
$$\large\sqrt2e^{\frac{i\pi}4}$$
Therefore
$$(1+i)^i=\sqrt2^ie^{-\frac{\pi}4}=e^{-\frac{\pi}4}\left(\cos\ln\sqrt2+i\sin\ln\sqrt2\right)$$